# I can't send keys using Selenium WebDriver and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to execute a simple test:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('http://google.com')
driver.find_element_by_name('q')
driver.send_keys('hey')
```

And I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/webdriver/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    driver.send_keys('hey')
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Did you try this? `driver.find_element_by_name('q').send_keys('hey')`

Comment: Helping Hands is right: use the send_keys method on the identified WebElement, not on the driver.

Comment: Thanks!
driver.find_element_by_name('q').send_keys('hey')
worked for me. But anyway why my code didn't?

Comment: @PavelPrakopchyk - Cheers...:) your code did not work because as per your code web driver getting confuse that where to send keys? because you have not use find element attribute with send keys so.

Answer (score 4):

The *[`WebDriver`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver) instance does not have a `send_keys()` method*. That's what the error is actually about:

> 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Call `send_keys()` on a [`WebElement`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) instance which is returned by `find_element_by_*()` methods - `find_element_by_name()` in your case:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
element.send_keys("hey")
```

---

And just FYI, there is also an [`ActionChains` class](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains) which is useful do build up chains of actions or apply more complex actions like drag&drop or mouse move. It's an overhead in this case, but just for the sake of an example:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).send_keys("hey").perform()
```

Comment: *driver.find_element_by_name* was deprecated and then removed (e.g., isn't in Selenium 4.12)

Comment: See e.g. *[Selenium - Python - AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_name'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72773206/selenium-python-attributeerror-webdriver-object-has-no-attribute-find-el/72773269#72773269)*: *"Selenium just removed that method in version 4.3.0... Deprecated `find_element_by_*` and `find_elements_by_*` are now removed ([#10712](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/10712))"*

Answer (score 1):

Did you try changing your reference element?

It would be a good practice if you call webdriver using a different reference.

Your code after changing the reference.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://google.com')
#Firefox Webdriver is created and navigated to google.

elem = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
elem.send_keys('hey',Keys.RETURN)
#Keys.RETURN = Pressing Enter key on keyboard

time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
```

Comment: `find_element_by_name` was [removed in Selenium 4.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72773206/selenium-python-attributeerror-webdriver-object-has-no-attribute-find-el/72773269#72773269).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is you do not have to tell the driver where to send the keys:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('http://google.com')
driver.find_element_by_name('q')
driver.send_keys('hey') // The driver doesn’t know where to send the keys
```

The correct code would be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('http://google.com')
goog = driver.find_element_by_name('q') // You have stored an element in the 'goog' variable
goog.send_keys('hey') // You told the variable to send 'hey'
```

Or you can directly send after finding the element like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('http://google.com')
driver.find_element_by_name('q').send_keys('hey')
```

Comment: `find_element_by_name` was [removed in Selenium 4.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72773206/selenium-python-attributeerror-webdriver-object-has-no-attribute-find-el/72773269#72773269).

Answer (score 0):

You must change the reference element

```
driver.get('http://google.com')
elem.find_element_by_name('q')
elem.send_keys('hey')
```

Comment: `find_element_by_name` was [removed in Selenium 4.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72773206/selenium-python-attributeerror-webdriver-object-has-no-attribute-find-el/72773269#72773269).

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue, but I got a solution for that.

Use `move_to_element` in `ActionChains`.

1. Find the element. `elem = driver.find_element_by_*`
2. Create your actionchain driver `actions = ActionChains(driver)`
3. use move to command, so *webdriver* will **point** to that element's position, but before you send the key, you need to **set** the *webdriver* position on that element by using the `click()` function. Now, *webdriver* has a **surface area to place given keys (data)** and for that you will use `send_keys()` function. In the last just put `perform()` function to **execute** these all task very smoothly.

`actions.move_to_element(<ELEMENT>).click().send_keys(<DATA>).perform()`

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.htmlt

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('http://google.com')
elem = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(elem).click().send_keys('hey').perform()
```

Comment: `find_element_by_name` was [removed in Selenium 4.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72773206/selenium-python-attributeerror-webdriver-object-has-no-attribute-find-el/72773269#72773269).

Answer (score -1):

It’s with the version of Selenium which is causing the issue. I faced the same issue.

It’s with the Selenium version 3.3.3 which has the compatibility problem.

Try:

```
pip uninstall selenium
pip install selenium==3.3.1
```